# Windows drops connection when new data received to socket

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, windows-server-2008, twisted

I've made a service with twisted. Everything worked fine until I've moved to a new server. Now my service drops most of connections when new data is received.
The old server had 32 bit Windows XP installed and the new one is a VMWare VM on Intel Server with Windows Server 2008 64 bit. The Python and twisted versions are the same on both servers.

Here you can see a snippet of the problem:

```
ConnectionLost reason is: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion.
```

Python version is 2.7.5, Twisted 12.3

This is the example code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
from twisted.python import log

class GreenProtocol(protocol.Protocol):

def __init__(self):
    self.ip = ''
    self.port = 0

def connectionMade(self):
    self.ip = self.transport.getPeer().host
    self.port = self.transport.getPeer().port
    log.msg("[{0}:{1}] NEW CONNECTION".format(self.ip, self.port))  

def dataReceived(self, data):
    log.msg("[{0}:{1}] DATA".format(self.ip,         self.port))                                    

def connectionLost(self, reason):
    log.msg("[{0}:{1}] CONNECTION LOST".format(self.ip, self.port)) 

class GreenFactory(protocol.ServerFactory):
    protocol = GreenProtocol

if __name__ == '__main__':
    factory = GreenFactory()
    reactor.listenTCP(5678, factory)
    log.startLogging(DailyLogFile('log.txt', 'logs'), setStdout=False)
    reactor.run()
```

After the connection is established each client sends a message. But only 1 of 5-10 messages are logged. The majority of Clients is losing the connection after sending a message and the message is not received by the Server.

Apparently, the reason is:

```
Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: read error -- unknown (64)
```

P.S: I think it is not twisteds fault, because when I listen with a sniffer I get the same result.

P.P.S: There are about 700 Clients and only 70-100 of them can send data, all the other connections are dropped.

Comment: This is not nearly enough information to diagnose your issue.  Please reproduce the memory leak with a small program, and then put this program here.  If you *can't* reproduce the leak or the connection drop in a small program, then you need to understand your large program better.

Comment: I've added extra explanation and code that is used on server

Comment: This code does nothing if I run it.  Please attach a *complete* program.  http://sscce.org

Comment: I attached a complete program

Comment: Update the network adapter drivers and verify the physical ethernet cables/connections to the VMWare host are correct

Comment: Could it be firewall error?

Comment: Network adapter drivers up to date, firewall disabled. Now, I think the problem is not in server, something is blocking almost all of connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was that, provider changed tariff plan without any notice. New tariff plan limited the maximum number of connections.